# $3$ cards are chosen at random from a standard $52$-card deck. What is the probability that they form a pair?

Tags: probability

$3$ cards are chosen at random from a standard $52$-card deck. What is the probability that they form a pair? (A $3$-card hand is a `pair' if two of the cards match in rank but the third card is different. For example, $668$ is a pair, but $999$ is not.)

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

A pair of say Aces, then $\binom{4}{2}\cdot \binom{48}{1}$, and there are $13$ ranks, so choose a rank first that is to have $\binom{13}{1}$, thus the probability is: $\dfrac{\binom{13}{1}\cdot \binom{4}{2}\cdot \binom{48}{1}}{\binom{52}{3}}$

Answer (score 1):

We have dueling answers. My first attempt was to use ordered samples as
@user247327 did, but I was never sure I was counting everything.
Now, including the possibility that the second and third cards
are the same, I believe an updated version of that solution, correcting
a typo and adding a term is 
$$(3/51)(48/50) + (48/51)(3/50) + (48/51)(3/50) = 0.1694118.$$

This agrees with the elegant approach of @DeepSea, where
$$13(6)(48)/{52\choose 3} =  0.1694118.$$

A third approach, perhaps the simplest, is to subtract from $1$ the probability that
all three denominations are the same and the probability that all three
are different:

$$1 - (3/51)(2/50) - (48/51)(44/50) = 0.1694118.$$

---

Furthermore, I simulated ten million 3-card draws from a deck that accounts
simply for four cards of each denomination, and where there is exactly
one pair precisely when there are two denominations among the three
cards drawn. Within simulation error, the result is the same:
$0.16956 \pm 0.00024.$

```
deck = rep(1:13, times=4)
x = replicate(10^7, length(unique(sample(deck, 3))))  # Nr unique denom seen
mean(x==2)   # mean of logical vector is proportion of its TRUEs
## 0.1695554
2*sd(x==2)/sqrt(10^7)
## 0.0002373237
```

Here is a histogram of simulated results. From combinatorics above, we have exact results
(red dots). Your answer is $P(X = 2),$ where $X$ is the number of denominations
seen among the three cards; $P(X=1)$ is the probability of 'three of a kind'.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The first card can be anything.  There are then 51 cards left in the deck, 3 of them the same rank as the first card.  The probability of choosing the same rank is 3/51.  There are then 50 cards left in the deck, 48 of them NOT the same rank as the first two cards.  The probability of that is 48/50 so the probability of the first two cards being the same and the third not is (3/51)(48/50)= (1/17)(24/25)= 24/425.

Now, go back to the drawing the second card.  There are 51 cards left in the deck, 48 of them NOT the same as the first card.  The probability the second card is NOT the same as the first card is 48/51.  Now there are 50 cards in the deck 3 of them the same as the first card.  The probability the third card drawn is the same as the first card is 3/50.  The probability the first and third cards are the same, the second different, is (48/51)(3/50).  Of course, that is exactly the same as the previous answer, (3/51)(8/50).

The probability either of those happens, which is just the probability two cards are the same, the third is different, is (3/51)(8/50)+ (48/51)(3/50)= 2(3/51)(8/50)= 48/425.

Comment: I would have expected to see a corrected version of this by now.